# How to calculate $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{sin\theta}{1＋cos\theta}\frac{d\theta}{1+kcos\theta}(0< k < 1)$？

Tags: integration

How to calculate $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{sin\theta}{1＋cos\theta}\frac{d\theta}{1+kcos\theta}(0< k < 1)$？

Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $x=\cos(\theta)$ and $\; dx=-\sin(\theta)d\theta$,

the improper integral becomes

$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{(1+x)(1+kx)}$$

$$=\frac{1}{1-k}\int_{-1}^1(\frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{k}{1+kx})dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{1-k}[ln(\frac{1+x}{1+kx})]_{-1}^1$$

Your integral is divergent and it goes to $+\infty$.